# Pagination for a page created by the shortcode "Product"

Tags: shortcode, pagination, woocommerce-offtopic

My `searchDB` function searches products with the specified keyword, and returns an array of found ids.

Below is my page. How can I add a pagination is this page ?

```
            <div class="product-container">
                <?php
                    $my_products = searchDB($text);

                    foreach ($my_products as $value) {

                        echo do_shortcode('[product id="'.$value.'"]'); 

                    }
                ?>  
            </div>
```

P.S: searchDB uses $wmdb.

Comment: You mean `$wpdb`?

Comment: Also sharing `searchDB` function will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woocommerce doesn't have pagination optionality by default, you need a plugin or code it by yourself.